# Creating Instances/Testing code

Tags: java, instance

Arlight so i have all of this code that i have done, its quite a bit.. Basically its just making a banking account. I made code for Checking, and Savings account. All of this code is correct. i just need help with making an instance of Savings and Checking accounts in my `Testaccount` class.

**Main Account code:**

```
public class Accountdrv {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Account account = new Account(1122, 20000, 4.5);

    account.withdraw(2500);
    account.deposit(3000);
    System.out.println("Balance is " + account.getBalance());
    System.out.println("Monthly interest is " +
      account.getMonthlyInterest());
    System.out.println("This account was created at " +
      account.getDateCreated());
  }
}

class Account {
  private int id;
  private double balance;
  private double annualInterestRate;
  private java.util.Date dateCreated;

  public Account() {
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
  }

  public Account(int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate) {
    this.id = id;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
  }

  public int getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
  }

  public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
    return annualInterestRate;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id =id;
  }

  public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
  }

  public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
  }

  public double getMonthlyInterest() {
    return balance * (annualInterestRate / 1200);
  }

  public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
  }

  public void withdraw(double amount) {
    balance -= amount;
  }

  public void deposit(double amount) {
    balance += amount;
  }
}
```

**Savings:**

```
class Savings extends Account{
  public Savings(int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate) {
  super(id, balance, annualInterestRate);
 }
public void withdraw(double amount) {
    if(super.getBalance() < amount)
    {
       System.out.println("Error");
    }
    else
    {
       super.withdraw( amount  );
       System.out.println("Withdraw Completed");
        }
    }
}
```

**Checking:**

```
public class Checking extends Account{
   private double overdraft_limit = 100;
    public Checking(int id, double balance, double annualInterestrate){
        //super();
        super(id, balance, annualInterestrate);
    }
        public void withdraw(double amount) {
            if(super.getBalance() >= (amount + overdraft_limit))
            {
                System.out.println(" account Overdrawn");
            }
            else
            {
                super.withdraw( amount );
                System.out.println("Withdraw Completed");

            }
        }
    }
```

Okay this is the part where i need help, its probably really simple but i can't wrap my head around how to write it out,i need to create an instance of Savings and Checking and withdraw some money, here is what i did so far.

**Testaccount:**

```
public class Testaccount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account = new Account(0, 100, 0.6);
        System.out.println(account);
        account.withdraw(10.50);
        System.out.println(account);
        account.deposit(5.0);
        System.out.println(account);

        // Need to add test cases for Savings and Checking
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider using `JUnit` or another framework  for testing your code

Comment: Did you notice the class 'Accountdrv' in the same file as your 'Account' class.  That is pretty much what you want to do.  Now just think of relevant cases to test.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to use the information already existing in the Account instance you created? If not (i.e. you want to create a new checking and savings account with initial amount in them) you could do something like

```
Checking checking = new Checking(0,100,0.6);
checking.withdraw(50.00);
```

Otherwise, if you want to use the existing Account instance and make it a Checking account and withdraw, do the following:

```
Checking checking = (Checking) account;
checking.withdraw(50.00);
```